# "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object" with filter function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter, typeerror

I have a list and I want to filter the tuples in this list using the filter function, but I'm running into a problem that I can't solve.

My code:

```
liste = [(3,4,5),(6,8,10),(3,10,7)]

def ucgen_mi(s):
    for g in s:
        a, b, c = g
        if (a + b > c and a + c > b and c + b > a):
            return True
        else:
            return False


print(list(filter(ucgen_mi, liste)))
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Çalışmalar\Çalışmalar\Gömülü Fonksiyonlar\P2.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(list(filter(ucgen_mi, liste)))
  File "D:\Python Çalışmalar\Çalışmalar\Gömülü Fonksiyonlar\P2.py", line 19, in ucgen_mi
    a, b, c = g
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I tried this way too, but the result is the same. It gives error on this line:  `for a,b,c in s:`

```
for a,b,c in s:def ucgen_mi(s):
    for a,b,c in s:
        if (a + b > c and a + c > b and c + b > a):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

To test the algorithm I wrote, I tried the bundles in the list separately and found that they were filtered the way I wanted.
`

```
liste = [(3,4,5)]

def ucgen_mi(s):
    for g in s:
        a, b, c = g
        if (a + b > c and a + c > b and c + b > a):
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(ucgen_mi(liste))
# result: True
```

Also:

```
liste = [(3,10,7)]

def ucgen_mi(s):
    for g in s:
        a, b, c = g
        if (a + b > c and a + c > b and c + b > a):
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(ucgen_mi(liste))
# result: False
```

Where am I doing wrong, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter implicitly loops over the `liste`, therefore your function only needs to take care of a single element at a time:

```
def ucgen_mi(g):
    a, b, c = g
    if (a + b > c and a + c > b and c + b > a):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Example:

```
print(list(filter(ucgen_mi, [(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10), (3, 10, 7)])))

# result: [(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10)]
```

---

The error message `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object` can be understood as follows:

When `filter` checks whether the first element `(3, 4, 5)` meets the requirements, it is passed to `ucgen_mi`, therefore `s` equals `(3, 4, 5)`. Then you loop over `s` (`for g in s`) and `g` becomes `3`. Then you try to unpack `g` (`a, b, c = g`), which does not make sense (=> "cannot unpack non-iterable int object").

Comment: Ah yes the problem is completely solved, now I fully understand the problem. The loop I used was a completely unnecessary logical error, I should have tried to be simpler. It was really self explanatory, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`filter` function take, a function or None, and iterable.

here is doc of `filter`

```
class filter(object)
 |  filter(function or None, iterable) --> filter object
 |  
 |  Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable for which function(item)
 |  is true. If function is None, return the items that are true.
```

it take single iterable object from iterable (list/dict/tuple/generator) and do calculation on it ie it is kinda same as `lambda x: x if func(x)`

you need to modify the function such that, it calculate for each iterable object not whole list at a time.

below is a sample improved code

```
def ucgen_mi(array):
    a, b, c = array
    if (a+b > c) and (a+c > b) and (b+c>a):
            return True
    return False 
liste = [(3,4,5),(6,8,10),(3,10,7)] 
result = list(filter(ucgen_mi, liste))
print(result)
# [(3, 4, 5), (6, 8, 10)]
```